# Suggestion on flutter calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I need suggestion on the best calendar widget package in flutter. I tried syncfusion calendar. I need similar like that. https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-calendar

Answer (score 1):

You can use smart_calendar, it is an easy and customizable calendar widget, to use it, first you will initialize the controller and set the default dates like this:

```
final controller = SmartCalendarController(
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    lastDate: DateTime.utc(2053, 04, 31),
    locale: 'en_US',
    calendarType: CalendarType.civilCalendar,
    weekdayType: WeekDayType.medium,
  );
```

And then just call the widget like this:

```
SmartCalendar(controller: controller)
```

Like I said, easy, you can get the library from here https://pub.dev/packages/smart_calendar

Answer (score 0):

Use this calendar library:
Easy to customize and use
https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar